# How can I display a specific Edit Form based on the current View?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a few custom Edit forms I've created in SharePoint Designer for the same content type. Is there any way to bind a specific edit form to each list view or user group natively in SharePoint, or will I have to write something to handle the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifications through javascript can be bound to content types or list templates through elements.xml (farm solution) however to set custom forms (application pages), you will have to do this through a script (powershell).

You should be able to loop through the lists and just set the URL for the edit-form. There is a EditFormUrl parameter on the SPContentType object and an equivalent will exist for powershell of course.